# page not redirected to the servlet in MVC

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have made an app in MVC where though i redirect it to the view page through controller it either shows a blank page or shows null pointer exception.
controller is as:

```
        else if(req_type.equals("Publisher"))
                {
            Object[][] pub=null;
                try {
            pub = gs.getPublisherDetails();
            }     catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    session.setAttribute("pub",pub);
                response.sendRedirect("Publisher.jsp");
               }
```

also my model is:

```
public Object[][] getPublisherDetails() throws SQLException
    {
        //group_id=request.getParameter("group_id");
            Object[][] pub=null;
        String query="SELECT * FROM `publisher`";
        ResultSet rs1=(ResultSet) DataService.getResultSet(query);
        pub = (Object[][]) DataService.getDataFromResultSet(rs1);
        return pub;

    }
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is because `pub` may be `null` . so it is better to refine your code like this ,

```
else if(req_type.equals("Publisher"))
                {
            Object[][] pub=null;
                try {
            pub = gs.getPublisherDetails();
                                    session.setAttribute("pub",pub);
                response.sendRedirect("Publisher.jsp");   
            }     catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

               }
```

Comment: no this is not helping!! still in the url i can see that it takes the req_type- publisher but not processing its request and getting me a blank page and doesnot execute the query even

Comment: What is `gs` and have you checked whether `getPublisherDetails()` returns the desired result ?

Comment: GlobalService gs = new GlobalService();
my business service is GlobalService where i have defined that query.
Also query executes and give the results i can see that in console

Comment: Can you post the stack traces from your server

Comment: req_typereq_typereq_type::::verifyUser
req_typereq_typereq_type::::verifyUser
parent_orgparent_org  0
0
queryquery  select org_name from organization where org_id='0'
SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE org_id=1 and groups_id not in (0) ORDER BY groups_id ASC;
null
getIncomingCallLogQuery    SELECT `caller_id`,`time` FROM `incoming_call` where groups_id=31  ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;